# SQLite3 Concatenation Query Fails for some reason

Tags: python, sqlite, concatenation

Why does the following SQLite3 query fail with the error:

> SQL Exception: near "||": syntax error

My Query:

```
UPDATE test 
SET money_links||='http://www.test.com', u_links||='http://www.test.com' 
WHERE u_tag='test2';
```

The structure of the table test is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  test(u_tag TEXT PRIMARY KEY, money_links TEXT, u_links TEXT);
```

Comment: What's the '||' for ? I've never it before.

Comment: It's for concatenation, so it performs the same function as '+='

Comment: It fails because this is not SQL or SQLite syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE test 
SET money_links = money_links + 'http://www.test.com', u_links = u_links+ 'http://www.test.com' 
WHERE u_tag='test2';

UPDATE test 
SET money_links = ISNULL(money_links,'') + 'http://www.test.com', u_links = ISNULL(u_links,'') + 'http://www.test.com' 
WHERE u_tag='test2';
```

Comment: thanks for the answer :) The query is now executing but it doesn't combine the existing strings in money_links(or u_links) with the new string, instead the value in money_links(and u_links) becomes '0'. What do you think is happening?

Comment: You had a null to start with -- see new version

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do something like this?

```
UPDATE test 
SET money_links = money_links || 'http://www.test.com',
    u_links = u_links || 'http://www.test.com' 
WHERE u_tag='test2';
```

I am afraid SQL does not allow such "incremental concatenation" like some real programming languages.